# Some tips on how to batch name a multiple files in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am working with files and after processing them, I need to save them with numerical names in an ascending order such as 1.txt, 2.txt and so on.
Manually I would do as below:

```
Variable_1 = "C:\\1.txt"
Variable_2 = "C:\\2.txt"
```

Comment: There is no real question here. I do not see your problem with the description you gave. Please add more to it.

Comment: He wanted to automate i suppose, but i reckon your point. Also, ardit, you should try something before asking for help here (check on the faqs how you should ask a proper question http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
    filename = "C:\\%d.txt" % i
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        ....
```

it's as simple as this, but you could also use generators to create filenames (it's up to you)

Comment: I think "C:\\%d.txt" % i is a good tip.